# WebSpellChecker in CKEDITOR is not working

Tags: ckeditor, spell-checking

If I try to see the suggestion of any word then its only giving me loading ..
can you please tell me whats the issue and how it can be fixed ?

I am not able to find out how to fix it.

Please help me if anyone know how to fix it.[Loading error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oYhN.png)

Comment: This question is neither on-topic nor compliant with the How To Ask.  Try raising an issue on the ckeditor github repo.

Comment: ^ And anyway, Just let the browser handle spell checking.

Comment: I asked them but they denied to help as I am  not a paid customer.

Comment: If you can help then it will be helpful.
Please see the image attached so that  you can see the error .Its not showing the suggestion its only showing the loading..

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records. Here is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/WebSpellChecker/ckeditor-plugin-wsc/issues/54) related to this request. It has been resolved.

Comment: Yes, i fixed the issue by changing the wcs folder in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i fixed the issue by changing the wcs folder in the plugin.